# Firebase MLKit Android from an external camera

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, yuv, firebase-mlkit

I believe I found a bug in the **Firebase MLKit for Android**, but perhaps other people have some insight into it.

I am currently streaming video from a drone to my Android device. It is being decoded to `YUV420-888` with `MediaCodec`and written to an `InputReader` surface. When I pass the `Image` received in the `InputReader` callback to MLKit using `fromMediaImage`, *there are no errors but it fails to detect anything in the image*. If I convert the `Image` to a `Bitmap` using `PixelCopy` and then pass that into MLKit with `fromBitmap`, it then succeeds at detecting features in the image.

I think the problem may be that the video is not originating from the phone's camera, but rather from an external camera on the drone (therefore not using `Camera2` APIs). I know my video feed is working in general because it can be previewed on a `SurfaceView` and because it works after being turned into a `Bitmap`. This leads me to believe that the MLKit parsing of `YUV420-888` data must be incorrect and that is what leads to the issue.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144854/how-to-use-image-format-yuv-420-888-for-mlkit-of-google) or [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348) ?

Both solutions seem to involve a format conversion or editing of the metadata

Comment: Have you found a way to use a USB camera with android and ML-kit with CameraX?